# Selenium WebDriver Java cannot find element in Chrome to scroll to

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I have a Web application with a scroll-able menu on the left hand side. My code is pretty simple:

```
WebElement elementToScrollTo = driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elementToScrollTo);
```

locator is the link to the web element/menu item I want to click. The problem is in Chrome, the first line throws a `NoSuchElementException`. So obviously I cannot scroll to something that cannot be found in the first place.

However, what's weird is that in IE everything works perfectly. The element can be found and the menu scrolls. After which I use the element (i.e. click on it).

I cannot scroll the entire browser window as I only need the menu panel on the left hand side to scroll.

I have the latest `Chrome (60.0.3112.78 (Official Build) (64-bit))` and `chromedriver 2.30`.

Note: I've actually figured out the problem. The reason it cannot find it is because it doesn't scroll to the parent of the menu item, the level 2 element. so the second line (scrolling) doesn't do anything in Chrome and because of that the driver will not find the menu item on level 3 (the child of level 2). So maybe scrolling doesn't work in Chrome?

Comment: Can you give me the complete code, so that i could try?

Comment: Please share the complete code

Comment: The error says it all `NoSuchElementException` as different browsers represents the `HTML DOM` differently. Thanks

Comment: The source code is pretty big. The link to the menu item is received through the method's arguments. Please note that it is found in IE. The error looks like this:  org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ul[contains(@style, 'block')]/li[@class='shell-menu-item-level-3']/div/a[text() = 'Users']"}

Answer (score 0):

It might be problem with the HTML elements located within a `frame`. To deal with such elements you need switch the frames first.

Can you try this command:
`driver.switchTo().frame()`

Also, try to use `implicitWait` if the above one doesn't work. Maybe, your element is taking time to load and therefore web driver fails to locate it.

`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`